# Bot: How make a field read only in Bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, adaptive-cards

Is there any way where we can make a field in bot framework as read only.
Below is the code which I have used in Adaptivecard for the field.
The don't want change the value of Owner and can we change the color of placeholder value?

```
 {
        "type": "Input.Text",
        "id": "Owner", 
        "placeholder": "Sree"
 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there is no attribute to make an `Input.Text` readonly. [You can see the schema here for yourself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/card-schema#inputtext). I would suggest not using an `Input` at all and just use a `TextBlock` instead which also allows you to control the color of the text where as `Input.Text` does not.